# Vuetify data table universal component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="this.headers"
    :items="this.items"
    hide-actions
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [],
      headers: [],
      attributes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadItems (items) {
      items.forEach(item => {
        var counter = 0
        var obj = `{\n`
        attributes.forEach(attribute => {
          obj += '"' + attribute + '" : ' + item[counter]
          if (counter < attributes.lenght)
            obj += ',\n'
          else
            obj += '\n'
          counter++;
        })
        obj += '}'
        this.items.push(obj)
      })
    },
    loadHeaders (headers) {
      headers.forEach(header => {
        this.headers.push({ text: header, value: header.toLowerCase()})
        this.attributes.push(headers)
      })
    },
    loadTable (items, headers) {
      this.loadHeaders(headers)
      this.loadItems(items)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Will those functions work to dynamically build an data table with custom items and headers?
I want to build an data table component which will be an universal for each data table from my SQLlite3 database.
How to change the template to display custom attributes of items from attributes array?